# Drop-down menu based on the selection of radio button

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I have four radio buttons and I would like to get the drop-down menu based on the selected radio button. Is it best if I just write all those drop-downs ready and display them based on the selection or is there a way to do it with ajax (because the drop-down values are coming from database) ?
Here are the radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="some" value="someValue1">
<input type="radio" name="some" value="someValue2">
<input type="radio" name="some" value="someValue3">
<input type="radio" name="some" value="someValue4">
```

Here is the drop-down:

```
<select name="reason">
<?php
$data = WorkReason::all();
foreach ($data as $d) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $d->code; ?>"><?php echo $d->reason; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

I am using php ActiveRecords to get the values from database.
So if anybody knows a good way of doing this I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the different drop down lists and add a php condition to check which radio button was clicked and display that list.
You can use an array to select the correct code for you.

```
$radio2select = array ("someValue1" => "<select>..." , "someValue2" => "...", "someValue3" => "..."); // you get the idea
echo $radio2select($_REQUEST['radio']) ;
```

The use of an array is a trick to avoid using a switch statement, and it works well when your drop down boxes have been precomputed.

Otherwise, make a function which build the drop down box:

```
function select_reasons($which){
<select name="reason">
<?php
  $data = WorkReason::all(array('conditions' => array ( 'reason = ?' => $which)));
  foreach ($data as $d) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $d->code; ?>"><?php echo $d->reason; ?></option>
<?php
 }
?>
</select>
}
```

then just pass the `$_REQUEST[‘radio']` to generate the corresponding dropdown list.

Note that I don't know your database schema, but I think that it should get you started.

Also, this code will work either on a regular Get or Post, or could be embedded within an ajax roundtrip (this depends on the framework you are using).
Another advantage is that only the necessary html code get included in the page, compared to a CSS based solution.

Comment: Can you maybe add an example, I really don't get it.

Comment: But this would require a page refresh to get the value from radio button to the function ?

Comment: Yes, unless you embed the function in an ajax call, the page will have to go through a refresh to get the new dropdown list.

Comment: The ajax part is easy to do, but you need to choose a js librarie, and the ajax call implementation depends on it.

Comment: Then I have to do it with ajax, because I don't want to refresh the page. Anyways thank you very much for all of your help, I appreciate it :).

Answer (score 1):

Make the different drop down lists and add a php condition to check which radio button was clicked and display that list.

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox1']) {

echo '<select>...'

} else if (isset($_POST['checkbox2']) {

echo '<select>...'

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking of that, but then I thought maybe there is a easier way to do it with ajax. Less code and everything, but I'll see what others think and then decide.

Comment: Ajax simply hides the refresh of the page, but PHP logic remains the same.

Comment: No refresh would be nice, but I can make that happen with javaScript also, so I guess it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just load all Dropdown menues and display the one the user chose earlier with CSS:

```
display:block
display:none
```